# Simulating exceptions using shim or stub

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How do you simulate exception scenarios in unit test case?

We have a function which calls a service and we handled an exception when the service goes down or there's some sort of issues at the service end.

Now I want to know how to simulate the service-down or service-access-denied in unit test case using shim or stub.

Comment: Please review [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=unit+testing+exceptions+c%23+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and tell us which question most closely fits your situation.  See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx

Comment: what is the mocking and unit test framework used ?

Comment: Thanks Robert.

I looked into those links but most of the links shows how to test exception cases means they are sending invalid inputs and actual function raises an exception which are validated in the unit test cases using [ExpectedException] attribute.. 

but whereas for my case, I need to raise an webexception from the unit test cases using MS Fakes concept. either shim or stub.. since the actual function create request object, call the the service and returns the response. so I need to write unit test cases which simulates the webexpection scenario [service failure case].

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a mocking framework to simulate exceptions in the code under test.
There are several to choose from, but MOQ is a very popular one.

Here's an example of how it can be done:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/mock-exceptions-using-moq

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

but currently we need to go with ms unit test case framework.

Comment: It will work with MS Test. The example is using MS Test. MOQ is a third party open source library. It works with any testing framework.